# speed up kafka consumer processing but ensure ordering of events

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I know that if we have multiple partitions and almost the same number of consumers in the consumer group then the processing will speed up. If we want to maintain the ordering of the event and process each event as and when it is received, how can we achieve this with multiple partitions and consumers.

In my use case processing the events in order is extremely critical or else the system will fall apart. I wanted to use multiple partitions to increase parallelism but somehow 'get them in order'.

Comment: In general, if you absolutely need to order across partitions, you'd dump the data elsewhere like rdbms or Hadoop, then order by time there

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer: you can't

Once you split data to partitions, you can't guarantee order in consumption (even with single consumer).
Isn't there any logic in which you can shard the data into partitions, so that messages that has to be consumed in order would end up in same partition?